# Como recuperar dados do terminal com php?

Tags: php, git

Exemplo, eu tenho esse comando a seguir em um arquivo php:

```
<?php

$imprimir = shell_exec("cd /home/afonso/Documentos/teste; git add arquivo.txt; git commit -m 'testando'; git push -u origin master");
```

Até aqui funciona tudo bem, só que ele pede para eu colocar a senha do Bitbucket no terminal e eu quero "recuperar" essa parte, ou seja, em vez de digitar a senha no terminal eu quero que ele digite a senha em uma tela pela página do php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
echo shell_exec("cd /home/afonso/Documentos/teste; git add arquivo.txt; git commit -m 'testando'; git push -u origin master" 2>&1");
```

esse 2>&1 vai capturar tudo que seu terminal mostraria